ошибка, связанная с auth_clicker
в проекте имеется 3 приложения auth_clicker, backend, frontend.
мне нужно импортировать модели из backend
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Core(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    coins = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    click_power = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    level = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def click(self):
        self.coins += self.click_power
        if int(self.coins) >= self.check_lvl_price():
            self.level += 1
            return True
        return False

    def check_lvl_price(self):
        return (self.level ** 2 + 1) * 100 * (self.level + 1)


class Boost(models.Model):
    core = models.ForeignKey(Core, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lvl = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    power = models.IntegerField(default=1)

в файл frontend admin.py
    from django.contrib import admin
    from backend.models import Boost, Core
    
    admin.site.register(Boost)
    admin.site.register(Core)

но PyCharm ругается:
Unresolved reference 'backend'
Unresolved reference 'Boost'
Unresolved reference 'Core'

как исправить или вообще это влияет на работу ?
может мне IDE врет и все окей.
при выполнении миграции или запуска сервера вылезает совсем другая ошибка связанная с auth_clicker.
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'auth_clicker' from 'D:\\python\\Django_Clicker\\clicker\\auth_clicker\\__init__.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see the 'urlpat
terns' variable with valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос
